# Return true when user click a bug

Tags: javascript

I am making a bug smasher game, and want Boolean value(isOnCircle) to return 'true' when a user clicks the bug. However, it always returns 'false'. Although when I tested it as a circle instead of a bug image (with 'context.arc'), it returned 'true'.

*I also inserted an image into the canvas background.
bug.r=32 is the bug image's correct radius size.

```
var Bug = (function () {
    function Bug() {
    }
    return Bug;
}());
var jumpInterval;
var interval = 4000;
var bug = new Bug();
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width =727
    canvas.height = 483;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var background = new Image();
background.src = "images/lawn.jpg";

background.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
}

function handleClick(evt) {
    console.log(evt.x + ',' + evt.y);
    var x = evt.x - 50;
    var y = evt.y - 100;
    // (x - center_x)^2 + (y - center_y)^2 < radius^2
    var isOnCircle = Math.pow(x - bug.x, 2) + Math.pow(y - bug.y, 2) < Math.pow(bug.r, 2);

    console.log(isOnCircle);

    if (interval > 500) {
        interval -= 300;
    } else {
        interval = 500;
    }
    console.log(interval);
}
function jump() {
    bug.x = ((Math.random() * 10324897) % 500) + 1;
    bug.y = ((Math.random() * 10324897) % 500) + 1;
    bug.r = 32;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var background = new Image();
    background.src = "images/lawn.jpg";

    background.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    }


    console.log(bug.x);
    console.log(bug.y);



    context.beginPath();
     //context.arc(bug.x, bug.y, bug.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    var bugImage = new Image();
    bugImage.src = "images/bug.PNG";

    bugImage.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(bugImage, bug.x, bug.y);
    }
    context.stroke();

    clearInterval(jumpInterval);
    jumpInterval = setInterval(jump, interval);

}
jumpInterval = setInterval(jump, interval);
canvas.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

Comment: Are you taking into account that `drawImage`’s coordinates are the top-left of the image, but `arc`’s coordinates are the centre of the arc? Also, `((Math.random() * 10324897) % 500) + 1` is just `Math.random() * 500 + 1`.

Comment: No. I didn't know that. Thank you so much for the tip. That is very helpful. I will try to edit it.